# How to retain the previous version of app on user cancel - Wix Installer Upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

eI have an APP Installer using Wix.
Now I need to Upgrade the APP without uninstallation of the previous version. So I have been using the following method for upgrading my APP, Without uninstallation.

```
<Property Id="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" Secure="yes" />
<Upgrade Id="7c4d0532-0ee4-49e8-92f4-77792293fcab">
  <UpgradeVersion
     Minimum="1.0.0.0" Maximum="99.0.0.0"
     Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED"
     IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" />
</Upgrade>
```

And during installation of new version, it uninstalls the app and installs the new version.

But when user cancels the wizard immediatly after the unisntallation of the earlier version, The entire app is lost from the PC.
The new version installation gets cancelled and the prvious version gets uninstalled.
The Roll back operation is not happened and the previous version is not retaind.

Is there any method to Retain the previous version in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there's no other problem, the RemoveExistingProducts action must be between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize for the transaction to roll back and reinstall the old product. You didn't say where your REP is sequenced.

If it IS between those two actions then the issue may be that the reinstall of the original product is failing. It's just been uninstalled and is now being reinstalled as a rollback of its uninstall, and that scenario may not be one the product can deal with. Check the verbose log.

Comment: I have solved the issue already.. As you said REP was Sequenced  before InstallInitialize. Once it is made to After InstallInitialize, the problem is not found so far..